# ORACLE SQL: Return Most recently hired employees

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, inner-join

I am having trouble solving a problem with Oracle SQL. I have to return the most recently hired employees in each department. This would require me to use two tables: DEPARTMENTS and EMPLOYEES. I have to solve this problem without hard coding, meaning I can't use the WHERE clause and I must use a sub query. I must sort the table in ascending order first by department name then employee name. Then end result should resemble this:

[image]

I thought that an inner join might work and I have this for my code:

```
     SELECT d1.DEPARTMENT_ID , d1.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
     e1.EMPLOYEES_ID,e1.EMPLOYEES_NAME, e1.JOB_TITLE, e1.JOB_TITLE
     FROM DEPARTMENTS d1
     INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES e1
     ON d1.DEPARTMENT_ID = e1.DEPARTMENT_ID
     HAVING MAX(e1.HIRE_DATE) = (SELECT e1.HIRE_DATE
                        FROM EMPLOYEES
                        GROUP BY d1.DEPARTMENT_ID)
     ORDER BY d1.DEPARTMENT_NAME, e1.EMPLOYEES_NAME ASC;
```

DEPARTMENTS and EMPLOYEES share DEPARTMENT_ID attribute so I linked them there, but I am unsure of how to get the e1 attributes in the end result. I keep getting a few errors:

not a group by expression
not a single group function
too many values

If anyone could explain to me how to approach this problem or what I'm doing wrong, that would be great

Comment: is this a school project?   the can't use where is an odd restriction

Comment: Yes, it unfortunately is

Answer (score 0):

--You could also use rownumber

```
select *
from
(
SELECT d1.DEPARTMENT_ID , d1.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
         e1.EMPLOYEES_ID,e1.EMPLOYEES_NAME, e1.JOB_TITLE, e1.JOB_TITLE,
Row_number() over (partition by d1.DEPARTMENT_ID order by hiredate desc) as rn
         FROM DEPARTMENTS d1
         INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES e1
         ON d1.DEPARTMENT_ID = e1.DEPARTMENT_ID
)
where rn=1
```

Comment: What's a rownumber and what does it do?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Comment: also i can't use a where clause

Comment: where clause is restricting results to only "max hire date for each department "

Comment: understood, but I'm not allowed to use it anywhere in my solution

Comment: does your department table has hire date ?

Comment: OP stated this is a school exercise. Very unlikely they made it as far as "analytic functions." While this may be the best solution, it doesn't seem the right one for the OP's current level in his/her learning.

Answer (score 0):

@TheGameiswar give you good answer (use Row_number!), here based on him answer but without `WHERE` and here use subquery:

```
with dep(id,name) as (select 1, 'sales' from dual union all 
                      select 2, 'develop' from dual),
     emp(id,dep_id, name, hire_date) as (select 1,1,'john',sysdate from dual union all 
                                         select 2,1,'kim', sysdate-100 from dual union all
                                         select 3,1,'kim', sysdate-101 from dual union all
                                         select 4,2,'kate', sysdate-1000 from dual union all
                                         select 5,2,'richard', sysdate-300 from dual union all
                                         select 6,2,'jack', sysdate-500 from dual)

select dep.*, emp.*
  from dep inner join 
         (select emp.*, row_number() over (partition by emp.dep_id order by hire_date desc) rn from emp) emp 
    on dep.id = emp.dep_id
    -- here no WHERE clause :)
    and emp.rn = 1

order by dep.name,emp.name
```

output:

```
        ID NAME            ID     DEP_ID NAME    HIRE_DATE         RN
---------- ------- ---------- ---------- ------- --------- ----------
         2 develop          5          2 richard 29.09.15           1
         1 sales            1          1 john    25.07.16           1
```

or you can use double `group by` like this

```
with dep(id,name) as (select 1, 'sales' from dual union all 
                      select 2, 'develop' from dual),
     emp(id,dep_id, name, hire_date) as (select 1,1,'john',sysdate from dual union all 
                                         select 2,1,'kim', sysdate-100 from dual union all
                                         select 3,1,'kim', sysdate-101 from dual union all
                                         select 4,2,'kate', sysdate-1000 from dual union all
                                         select 5,2,'richard', to_date('1.07.2016','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
                                         select 6,2,'richard2', to_date('1.07.2016','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union all
                                         select 7,2,'jack', sysdate-500 from dual)

select * from dep inner join emp on dep.id = emp.dep_id
                  inner join 
              (select max(emp.id) emp_id from emp 
                      inner join (select max(hire_date) hdate from emp group by dep_id) emp_max
                         on emp.hire_date = emp_max.hdate 
                group by hdate) last_hire_emp 
  on emp.id = last_hire_emp.emp_id
order by dep.name,emp.name
```

output:

```
        ID NAME            ID     DEP_ID NAME     HIRE_DATE     EMP_ID
---------- ------- ---------- ---------- -------- --------- ----------
         2 develop          6          2 richard2 01.07.16           6
         1 sales            1          1 john     25.07.16           1
```

last example have 2 emp on hire_date, in this example i'am fetch with max(id)

Answer (score 0):

Inner join to a subquery that selects the max(hiredate) by department.

First, select the max hire date and group by department.

```
Select department_id, max(hiredate) hiredate
from employees
group by department_id
```

Now we'll use this as a subquery and inner join it to the rest of the employee data.  The inner join here functions as your filter (or where clause)

```
select (pick your fields)
from
  (Select department_id, max(hiredate) hiredate
   from enmployees
   group by department_id) maxhire
inner join  DEPARTMENTS d1
  on d1.department_id = maxhire.department_id
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES e1
  ON d1.DEPARTMENT_ID = e1.DEPARTMENT_ID
  and maxhire.hiredate = e1.hiredate
```

This methodology will return multiple results if there was multiple people that were hired on the most recent hiredate.

Comment: ... or the first join may be a right outer join, to catch departments with NO employees (having a few nulls in the employee columns). Such departments sometimes do exist.

Answer (score 0):

So I did some more figuring and came up with this:

```
    set linesize 200
    SELECT DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID AS 
    "DEPARTMENT ID",DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME AS "DEPARTMENT NAME", 
    EMPLOYEES_ID AS "EMPLOYEE ID", 
    EMPLOYEES_NAME AS "EMPLOYEE NAME", MAX(HIRE_DATE) AS "HIRE DATE"

    FROM EMPLOYEES

    INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS

    ON DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID 

    GROUP BY DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID, 
    DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME, EMPLOYEES_ID, EMPLOYEES_NAME

    ORDER BY DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME;
```

This works up until it comes to the most recent date being first for each department. So would this be where the subquery comes in to make sure the max date for each department name is the most recent?